# Minifying only a part of .LESS file

Tags: css, less

When working with .less preprocessor files, is there any GUI tools such as Winless, etc. or in Grunt, to just minify a section of the outputted CSS file?

For eg. in the final .CSS, I want the main code to remain neatly formatted but the reset code or normalize include to be minified.

E.g. https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper/blob/master/assets/css/screen.css

In this file, either we can minify everything and have a min.css which users could use, but I want to know if there is any automated option to only minify part of it, for e.g. the normalize reset section.

Comment: What's your reasoning for wanting to do this? For a dev environment, it really doesn't matter if things like reset aren't minified. And for a production environment, there's absolutely no need or reason that anything should **not** be minified. Perhaps if you explain your reasoning, your question might make a little more sense.

Comment: Hi @ChristianVarga, sure I will. When creating themes to share with others, I do provide a minified file, but in the un-minified version, I would like minify general styling rules that do not need to be edited. Now developers could take my .LESS files and directly use it for customization, but for some who prefer editing CSS instead, I want to make it little easier.